# Wha is the difference between two instructions in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

let's say that i have a buffer of 2 bytes size and some value (not address) in register ax and now i write

```
mov buffer,ax

mov [buffer],ax
```

These kind of doubts are very common for me as i am new to assembly. Please suggest me some nice text so that i can clear my doubts about memory addressing. thanks in advance.

Comment: Read NASM documentation, section "2.2.2 NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References" in particular. And don't forget to read the CPU documentation.

Comment: What assembler are you talking about? Is it still NASM or something else? If it's NASM, are you sure NASM doesn't generate any error messages for the `mov buffer,ax` instruction?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference!

Compiler should compile both instructions into the same op codes.
Number inside square brackets `[]` is considered as memory address.

Because is `buffer` declared as word ptr there is no need to be declared again.

Comment: Based on the last question from the OP, I bet this is asked about NASM, in which case the two instructions will be compiled to different opcodes. Honestly, I don't even understand how `mov buffer, ax` could assemble with NASM. It gives me the error `error: invalid combination of opcode and operands`.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze: I don't know for NASM, but under Delphi asm are acceptable both combinations, of coursce `buffer` must be declared as word or you can also use prefix `word ptr`!